# Update a subtype attribute using TREAT (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle11g

I want to be able to update a subtype attribute, and some research has led me to believe it can be done with TREAT. I have tried a couple of variations on this syntax:

```
UPDATE table1 t SET TREAT(VALUE(t) AS myType).attributeToUpdate = 10 WHERE id=1;
```

myType is a subtype of the type of table1.

Keep getting the error `ORA-00927 missing equals sign`.

Thanks

Comment: old thread but I just recently faced the same issue. Has anyone solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use any of this bizarre "tables of objects" stuff so can't be sure, but it seems to me that TREAT is an expression, and you can't update the result of any expression, e.g. this is obviously illegal:

```
UPDATE emp SET UPPER(ename) = 'X'; -- Won't work
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work for you:

```
DECLARE
    s subclass;

BEGIN
    SELECT treat(value(p) as subclass) INTO s FROM superclass p WHERE id = search;
    s.attributeToChange = 'new value';
    UPDATE superclass p SET value(p) = s WHERE id = search;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know this question fully, but a reference book <> says to use DML to construct a new object

http://www.howardsmith.net/manuals/Oracle_PL_SQL_Programming.pdf

see page 1159

A better solution may be change the design of your type table, because sub type attribute is accessible, so maybe make it super type.